# Vertically center rotated text with CSS

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, centering, vertical-text

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner rotate">Centered?</div>
</div>
```

`div.outer` is a narrow vertical strip. `div.inner` is rotated 90 degrees. I would like the text "Centered?" to appear centered in its container div. I do not know the size of either div in advance.

This comes close: http://jsfiddle.net/CCMyf/2/. You can see from the jsfiddle that the text is vertically centered before the `transform: rotate(-90deg)` style is applied, but is somewhat offset after. This is particularly noticeable when `div.outer` is short.

Is it possible to center this text vertically without knowing any of the sizes in advance? I haven't found any values of `transform-origin` that solve this problem.

Comment: Are you opposed to setting `display: table` on the elements? Because the 'standard' way to vertically align dynamic divs should work with the transform without issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6182661/188221

Comment: I'm not opposed to ```display: table```. This fiddle shows that the table solution has the same issues as the one above: http://jsfiddle.net/4d384/

Comment: Try putting the `rotate` class on the middle element. That should do it, but it looks like it messes up the width of the item. Might have to play around with the padding or width or height props, but it should be do-able: http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/jWYuq/

Comment: Fixing the width issue is significantly harder than you'd expect. Putting ```min-width: 16px; width: 16px``` on ```.outer``` results in the exact same non-centering as in the original question.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The key is to set position top and left to 50% and then transformX and transformY to -50%.

```
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.rotate {  
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/CCMyf/79/

Comment: Working with text elements instead of divs I had to add `margin: 0` on the inner element to make the text center perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not so far. I don't know why but if I set the rotate rule first like this: `transform:  rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` it doesn't work, and if I put it last as your example shows, it works: `translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);`.

Comment: @MaximeLafarie Damn me too!  Just learned that transform have an execution order

Answer (score 6):

It may be a bit late for answering that question, but I stumbled on the same issue and found some way of achieving it, by adding another div in the way.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class='middle'><span class="inner rotate">Centered?</span></div>
</div>
```

and applying a `text-align: center` on that middle element, along with some positioning stuff:

```
.middle {
    margin-left: -200px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    left: 7px;
    top: 50%;
    line-height: 37px;
}
```

The `.inner` also gets a `display: inline-block;` to enable both `rotate` and `text-align` properties.

Here is the corresponding fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CCMyf/47/

Answer (score 5):

The another option to rotate text 90 degree and center on axis Y is:

```css
.rotate-centered {
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(-1) translate(-50%, 50%);
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
 }
```

```html
<span class="rotate-centered">Text<span>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/wwwebman/pen/KKwqErL

But because of bad support in IE/EDGE `writing-mode` does NOT work there:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Answer (score 2):

Can you add `margin: 0 auto;` to your "rotate" class to center the text.

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ff-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 16px;  /* transform: rotate() does not rotate the bounding box. */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Here's the fiddle updated with "margin: 0 auto": http://jsfiddle.net/CCMyf/3/. You can see that the "?" in "Centering?" is much closer to the top than the "C" is to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from 'bjnsn' is good but not perfect as it fails when the text contains space in it. For example he used 'Centered?' as text but if we changed the text to let suppose 'Centered? or not' then it will not work fine and will take the next line after space. Ther is not width or height defined for the inner div block.

```
.inner {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-color: #878787;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #DDD;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/touqeer_shakeel/f1gfy1yy/
But we can make the whole text centered align properly, by setting the inner div width equal to height of the outer div, line-height of inner div equal to the width of the outer div and setting the display flex property for inner div with align-items:center and justify-content:center properties.

```
.inner {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-color: #878787;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  line-height:40px;
}
$('#height').on('change', function(e) {
  $('.outer').css('height', $('#height').val() + 'px');
  $('.inner').css('width', $('#height').val() + 'px');
});
```

updated fiddle    https://jsfiddle.net/touqeer_shakeel/cjL21of5/

Answer (score 0):

Removing : `margin-top: -7px;` from `.inner` made the vertically rotated text centered for me.  It also made the horizontal text not centered.

Just remove the above code?

Comment: This may make it closer to being centered, but it still isn't properly centered. You can see this clearly in this version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CCMyf/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could add this:

```
$('.inner').css('margin-top', $(this).parent().height() - 2*$(this).height());
```

To your `.on('change')` function, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/hVhbp/

Comment: This works, though I would very much prefer a CSS solution if it's possible.

Comment: did you find a CSS solution?