# How to place block in vertical center in div?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML structure and this is based on Bootstrap template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"><span>Text</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-11"></div>
</div>
```

I rotated `text` to 90 degree:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

How to place this block `<span>Text</span>` by vertical center independent of parent block height?

Schema is:

[image]

Comment: can you recreate a snippet so we can see the code working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XrWzq/828/

Comment: there is no rotation as the span is inline element .. so this code doesn't reproduce what you have a i guess. There i no more CSS ?

Comment: @Karabah If you want to rotate the `span` you will have to set its display to something other that the default of inline. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XrWzq/829/)

Comment: I dont understand why block are not inline it gives 12 grid points in sum

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XrWzq/832/

Comment: Whats the problem with that last fiddle? What is your desired end result? Also, what are you referring to when you use the word "block"?

Comment: I updated question with illustration

Comment: I feel like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138723/vertically-center-rotated-text-with-css may help with this.

Comment: Yes, correct it is similar like I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the drawing you have done and using Bootstrap, you could to use `flex` properties like the following example :

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.d-flex {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-1"><span>Text</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-11">Moew....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do everything with div's ? I would suggest `table`...

If you looking for something like this -- http://jsfiddle.net/XrWzq/843/

(remove borders, and that's just what you want)